# Can I fetch existing data for JPA field that newly marked as @Transient?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transient, jpa-annotations

I have a JPA column that Im GOING to mark as @Transient. But I do have some data in that field that I want to move later.

I know that @Transient won't persist. But, can I still load those existing data to the memory to the Java world?

Comment: No, `@Transient` causes hibernate to ignore that field for every action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `@Transient`prevents JPA/Hibernate from any data access operation.

But if you have a field that you only want to read you can mark it read-only:

```
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String transientField;
```

Comment: Thank you @Simon I think this works for me. I just only need Transient behavior with reading privileges.

Comment: So if my answer works for you I would appreciate if you could accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: NOTE: tiny spelling mistake: should be `updatable`

Comment: I fixed the typo. Would you please be so kind to accept the answer?